# The method play_again is not working,it should invoke on button push but instead the app is crashing

Tags: java, android-studio

```
package com.example.tictactoe;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Random r = new Random();
        int i = r.nextInt(2);
        int a[] = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
        int b[][]= {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
        public void r1c1(View view) {
        // 0 means superman,1 means batman and 2 means empty.
                ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) view;
                String s= iv1.getTag().toString();
                int j = Integer.parseInt(s);
                iv1.setTranslationY(-1500);
                a[j] = i;
                if(i==0) {
                        iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.superman);
                        iv1.animate().translationYBy(1500).setDuration(300);
                        i=1;
                } 
                else {
                        iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.batman);
                        iv1.animate().translationYBy(1500).setDuration(300);
                        i=0;
                }
                for(int c[]:b){
                        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                        if(a[c[0]]==a[c[1]]&&a[c[1]]==a[c[2]]&&a[c[0]]==0){
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Superman won the game", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        b1.animate().alpha(1);
                }
                else if(a[c[0]]==a[c[1]]&&a[c[1]]==a[c[2]]&&a[c[0]]==1 ){
                        Toast.makeText(this,"Batman won the game", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        b1.animate().alpha(1);
            }
        }
    }
        public void play_again (View view) {
                Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                GridLayout gl = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
                for (int j = 0; j < gl.getChildCount(); j++) {
                        ImageView iv = (ImageView) gl.getChildAt(j);
                        iv.setImageDrawable(null);
                }
                Arrays.fill(a, 2);
                i = r.nextInt(2);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(i==0){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Superman will play first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Batman will play first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Following error occurs on pushing the play_again button
2020-05-15 12:19:27.196 16196-16196/com.example.tictactoe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tictactoe, PID: 16196
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.GridLayout
        at com.example.tictactoe.MainActivity.play_again(MainActivity.java:50)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: You've got the wrong `GridLayout` class imported. `import android.widget.GridLayout;` should be `import androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout;`

Comment: You were right it worked. Thanks a lot.